# How to make a picture similar to this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, skak

I would like to make a cover for my class notes!
The Board I can draw. I don't know how to put the strip (which will contain the title of the Lecture Notes) on the Board:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7} \foreach \y in {0,...,11}
    {
        \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "brown" : "white"}
        \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult}
        \path[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1);
    }
    \draw (0,0)--(0,12)--(8,12)--(8,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess that as you are in a stack exchange dedicated to LaTeX, you want to draw this with LaTeX? Do you know TikZ?

Comment: See the package `xskak` by Ulrike Fischer, the package can be found here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak

Comment: Yes, I want to draw this with LaTeX.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I would say there is no need to load such a package, since all the op wants is a grid, a single symbol and a colored box with a title. TikZ is enough for that, and beside the grid the op wants does not look like a 8 x 8.

Comment: @Clément: So go ahead and create it with TikZ

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : I think benedito could at least try to set the first elements of what he wants.

Comment: The Board I can draw. I don't know how to put the strip (which will contain the title of the Lecture Notes) on the Board.

Comment: If you post the board in form of a compilable document and maybe a king symbol that belongs to you and pleases your needs, I am sure that someone will help you. But this is just a "do it for me"-question. We are not here to do free work and I guess that's how you got the minus vote. So, improve your question! Btw, the lower part of the picture is exactly an 8x8 raster. So I would still take a glance on work by Ulrike Fischer!

Comment: Rather than taking a screenshot of the code, please copy and paste it directly into the question, so that people can then copy and paste the code into their own editors. Nonetheless, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @benedito: I retyped your code screenshot into something that others can copy-and-paste. However, `between origins` is causing problems on my end. Also why use `white!50!white`, since it's equivalent to `white`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stripe can be achieved using a simple `\node` filled with the desired color, with predefined width and height and with the `overlay` option so it overlays the grid; something along these lines (feel free to make the adjustments required according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm] 
\foreach \x in {0,...,7} 
  \foreach \y in {0,...,11} 
  { 
    \pgfmathparse{mod(\x+\y,2) ? "brown" : "white"} 
    \edef\colour{\pgfmathresult} 
    \path[fill=\colour] (\x,\y) rectangle ++ (1,1); 
  } 
\draw (0,0)--(0,12)--(8,12)--(8,0)--cycle;
\node[
  overlay,
  outer sep=0pt,
  text width=8cm,
  minimum height=2cm,
  fill=yellow!85!black,
  anchor=north west,
  minimum height=2cm,
  font=\LARGE\sffamily
  ]
  at (0,9)
  {Some text goes here; it is the title of the notes}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]